# How to plot numeric values in a column when values in another column are equal to specific number

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I get the numeric values in a column (let's say column 10) when the numeric values in another column (let's say column 9) are equal to a specific number and plot this in a graph.

e.g., When values of column 9 == 4, get the corresponding value of column 10 and plot.  I am using row index number as a marker for time.

I am plotting all of column 10 to get a waveform then I want to use the data of column 9 to add markers to my waveform that are representative of a command occurring at a certain point in time.

Here is my code:

```
E = csvread('Experiment_at_10_45_1.csv');
[signal_rows, signal_columns] = size(E);
t=(1:signal_rows)/128; %128 samples per second

%% SNR plot for down frequency
plot(t,E(:,13),'k')
```

I hope my explanation is clear, as I have attempted to use a minimum working example of my code for the first time.

Comment: The point of a [mcve] is so users can reproduce the issue with only what is provided in the question. Your example has a dependence on `'Experiment_at_10_45_1.csv'`, which nobody but you has. In the meantime I suggest taking a look at [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) and also [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use logical indexing to do this. You want to first create an array of `0` (false) and `1` (true) values where column 9 is equal to the value you want.

```
bool = E(:,9) == 4;
```

Then you'll want to use this `0` and `1` array as the row index. This will grab only the rows where column 9 was equal to 4. This is referred to as [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).

```
E(bool, 10)
```

Then you can plot this

```
plot(t(bool), E(bool, 10))
```

As pointed out though, it is possible that the values aren't *exactly* to 4 due to floating point representation. To get around this, you just want to check if they are "close enough" using a very small epsilon.

```
bool = abs(E(:,9) - 4) < 1e-12;
```

Comment: I think OP wants to index on `E(:,9)==4`

Comment: @BillBokeey Thanks. Still on my first cup of coffee, clearly.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do.  I have been trying to work this out for days now but I didn't realize that I needed to look into logical indexing.  Thanks a lot, you've made my day.